# how to find out what versions of maas maas-dns and maas-dhcp from terminal

Tags: server, maas

i would like to know how do you find out what version of maas is running on my ubuntu 14.4 installation

what command is used to find maas api version, maas-dns, maas dhcp. please be specific.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

`maas` is managed by `snap` in modern versions of Ubuntu, so we can query with `snap info`:

```
snap info maas | awk '/^installed:/ {print $2}'
```

---

### Older Ubuntu versions

`apt-cache policy maas{,-dns,-dhcp}` will tell you their packaged versions. You'll want to look at the `Installed` line. Here's a nice filtered version from a system not running any MAAS packages:

```
$ apt-cache policy maas{,-dns,-dhcp} | grep Installed -B1 -A1
maas:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.1+bzr2269-0ubuntu0.1
--
maas-dns:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.1+bzr2269-0ubuntu0.1
--
maas-dhcp:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.1+bzr2269-0ubuntu0.1
```

The Candidates are what would be installed if I installed MAAS (or if it were already installed, what it would be upgraded to).

---

And just in case, the `maas{,-dns,-dhcp}` is a Bash expansion which gets replaced with `maas maas-dns maas-dhcp` when run. I was just being lazy and didn't want to type "maas" a load of times.

Comment: can you add to your answer how to do the same for snap installations?

Comment: `snap info maas | grep installed`